# What is the running time of this Triple nested for loop?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Here is the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        for (int j = i-1; j < N; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k+2 < N; k++) {
                System.out.println(i*j);
                System.out.println(i);
                i=i+1;
             }
        }
    }
```

I believe it is O(N^2) since there's two N's in the for loops, but not too sure.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think this is a duplicated question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486543/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-nested-triple-for-loop

Comment: @unnik No, not quite.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather because the `i`-loop has a fixed limit. Saying it's *O(N^2)* is not wrong IMO but if we are strict, then the complexity is *O(N^2 * log(N))*.

*We can prove it more formally:*

First, let's get rid of the `i`-loop *for the analysis*. The value of `i` is incremented within the `k`-loop. When `N` is large, then `i` will get larger than `60` right in the first iteration, so the `i`-loop will execute just one iteration. For simplicity, let's say `i` is just a variable initialized with `0`. Now the code is:

```java
int i = 0;
for (int j = -1; j < N; j++) {      // j from - 1 to N - 1
    for (int k = 0; k+2 < N; k++) { // k from 0 to N - 1 - 2
        System.out.println(i*j);
        System.out.println(i);
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

If we are very strict then we'd have to look at different cases where the `i`-loop executes more than one time, but only when `N` is small, which is not what we are interested in for big O. Let's just forget about the `i`-loop for simplicity.

We look at the loops first and say that the inner statements are constant for that. We look at them separately.

[image]

We can see that the complexity of the loops is *O(N^2)*.

Now the statements: The interesting ones are the printing statements. Printing a number is obviously done digit by digit (simply speaking), so it's not constant. The amount of digits of a number grows logarithmic with the number. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231742/764990) for details. The last statement is just constant.

Now we need to look at the numbers (roughly). The value of `i` grows up to `N * N`. The value of `j` grows up to `N`. So the first print prints a number that grows up to `N * N * N`. The second print prints a number that grows up to `N * N`. So the inner body has the complexity *O(log(N^3) + log(N^2))*, which is just *O(3log(N) + 2log(N))*, which is just *O(5log(N))*. Constant factors are dropped in big O so the final complexity is *O(log(N))*.

Combining the complexity of the loops and the complexity of the executed body yields the overall complexity: *O(N^2 * log(N))*.

Ask your teacher if the printing statements were supposed to be considered.

Comment: The mistake is that it is not reasonable to assume that `println` is O(1). You can't possibly print `k` characters in less than `k` steps.

Comment: @Mo B. For the purposes of algorithmic time complexity, it's not usually an analysis of things _external_ to your algorithm (like how long `#println` takes), it's about the asymptotic growth of the runtime relative to _what_ your algorithm does. You tend to classify these things around a single, fixed variable (like loop iterations, number of additions or multiplications, etc).

Comment: @Rogue It's debatable what is *external* to an algorithm. If it's the purpose of the algorithm to print the output, it's certainly not external. If the OP includes the println in their toy example, I assume it's an essential part of the algorithm. Or at least an essential and non-negligible part of the *code* whose time complexity we are reasoning about.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is O(N^2 log N).

First of all, the outer loop can be ignored, since it has a constant number of iterations, and hence only contributes by a constant factor. Also, the `i = i+1` has no effect on the time complexity since it only manipulates the outer loop.

The `println(i * j)` statement has a time complexity of `O(bitlength(i * j))`, which is bounded by `O(bitlength(N^2)) = O(log N^2) = O(log N)` (and similarly for the other `println`-statement. Now, how often are these `println`-statement executed?

The two inner loops are nested and and both run from a constant up to something that is linear in `N`, so they iterate `O(N^2)` times. Hence the total time complexity is `O(N^2 log N)`.